# How to detect new line while reading file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a file which works fine. But when I reach to where in the file it skips to the next line (or makes a newline), I'm trying to find the escape character `'\n'`, but it never mentions it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public static void main(String args[]) {
       File file = new File("Directory to file");
       try {
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           char current_char;
           while (fis.available() > 0) {
               current_char = (char) fis.read();
               if (current_char == '\n') {
                  System.out.println("We found the newline!!");
               }
            }
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

And the file it reads from contains this:

```
  This is the first line!
  This is the second line!
```

Comment: Unrelated but from the docs: "*`FileInputStream` is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using `FileReader`.*"

Comment: Just tried this locally - works like a charm...

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Test to see what chars your file actually contains: `System.out.printf("%s: 0x%02x%n", current_char, (int) current_char);`

Comment: There are three types of newlines for different environments https://confluence.qps.nl/fledermaus/questions-answers/other/differences-in-end-of-line-characters-mac-windows-and-linux

Comment: That's probably unrelated, but available() doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, there is a good case that it is useless. Never rely on available() to do anything you'd expect, so in reality never use it, never call it and forget it exists. If you use it for something you'll fail, because it doesn't do that thing.

Comment: You should be using `BufferedReader.readLine()` for this task.

Comment: @Simulant OP isn't comparing `String`s, he's comparing `char` primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Different platforms use different characters for new lines. You should better check the character's type instead of comparing to any literal:

```
if (Character.getType(current_char) == Character.LINE_SEPARATOR) {   
   System.out.println("We found the newline!!");
}
```

Comment: What about Windows though? Will it catch both \r and \n?

Comment: Unfortunately that fails.  Unicode’s [line-separator](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-26.html#General_Category_Values) category includes neither `\n` nor `\r`, only `\u2028`.  So `Character.getType('\n') == LINE_SEPARATOR` → `false`